# How to create custom camera in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, camera

I am doing an android and iOS application use to Phonegap and jQuery mobile. I want to do a application which similar
 this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.supersoftware.mangacamera&hl=vi

Now I having a problem with custom camera. do you help me? or suggest similar solution.

Thank for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly, and you want to customize the camera plugin coming with phonegap.

In this case, follow the instructions on [Cordova Camera Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera). The optional parameter  [cameraOptions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) really brings you a bunch of possibilities to configurate the camera.

If those possibilities are not sufficient for your purpose, you might want to download the source of the camera plugin and change the plugin itself. This needs a lot more time and effort. However, if you feel like doing it, these links may help you:

- [Camera Plugin Source](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-camera.git;a=summary)
- [Plugin development guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

Comment: Thanks miweiss. I try.. if success i will reply to you.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a [tutorial](https://blog.sffc.xyz/post/182052843340/writing-a-custom-camera-plugin-for-phonegap) for how to build a custom camera for iOS as a PhoneGap plugin.  What it boils down to is an expression like this in JavaScript:

```
cordova.exec(function(){
    console.log("success", arguments);
}, function(){
    console.log("failure", arguments);
}, "CustomCamera", "openCamera", []);
```

This essentially calls `[CustomCamera openCamera:command]` over in Objective-C.  You just need to make a `CustomCamera` class extending `CDVPlugin` and implementing an `openCamera` method.

The primary camera interface in iOS is [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).  In the openCamera method, you can open the UIImagePickerController as a modal view.  UIImagePickerController has a delegate method that is called when the picture is snapped.  In this delegate method, you need to do something like this:

```
[self.commandDelegate
    sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult
        resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
        messageAsString:imagePath]
    callbackId:self.latestCommand.callbackId];
```

where `self.latestCommand` is a reference to the `command` argument passed to `openCamera`.  This will go and call the success function (first argument) in `cordova.exec`.

Note that in order for this to work properly, you need to add the following to `config.xml`:

```
<feature name="CustomCamera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CustomCamera" />
</feature>
```

Hope that helps!